# Center label instance inside VGroup in Flex

Tags: alignment, flex4, center

I am trying to center my labels below my image inside my VGroup. The labels are align to left now and it seems like HorizontalAlign is not working on spark component. Anyone knows how to fix it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:VGroup width="800">

        <mx:Image source="images/big/city1.jpg"/>
        <s:Label text="test1" horizontalCenter="0" /> //doesn't work....:(
        <s:Label text="test2" />


    </s:VGroup>

</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this,

```
<s:Label text="test1" width="100%" textAlign="center" />
```

you need to specify the width of Label in order to take effect its alignment.